# Accessing outside variable from class when using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python

In the following code snippet:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

class Flight(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "flights"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    origin = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    destination = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    duration = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)

    def add_passenger(self, name):
        p = Passenger(name=name, flight_id=self.id)
        db.session.add(p)
        db.session.commit()
```

why `db` inside the class can be used as global variable without `global`? I checked [python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python) and found:

> In Python, variables that are only referenced inside a function are implicitly global.

I wonder does this rule apply here? Because `db` is not only referenced but modified in `add_passenger` method.

Comment: You are not assigning anything to the variable `db` inside any functions. `add_passenger` is only calling a method. It alters only internal state, not the reference itself. If you did `db = SQLAlchemy()` inside a function then you'd need `global`.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not assigning anything to the variable `db` inside any functions.

`add_passenger` is only calling a method. It alters only internal state, not the reference itself.

If you did

```
db = SQLAlchemy()
```

inside a function then you'd need to use `global`, otherwise, you'd just get another variable called `db` at the local scope and using it would not have any effect on the global `db` object.